# Windows 7 not letting me format drive that has Vista installed on it

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, hard-drive, format

My computer has three hard drives, one with Windows 7 installed, one with Vista installed, and one storage drive.  For a while I was dual-booting W7 and Vista, but now that I no longer need the Vista installation I'd like to format that drive.

I used [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to remove the option of booting to Vista.  (My computer now boots directly to W7.)  There is no longer any data I wish to keep on the Vista drive at all.  When I go to Disk Management in Windows 7, however, it will not let me format the drive.  It gives the error: "Windows cannot format the system partition on this disk."

What steps do I need to take to format the Vista drive so that I can re-purpose it?

If it matters, in Disk Management it lists the Vista drive as Drive 0, my storage drive as Drive 1, and my W7 drive as D2.

Comment: I'm guessing some boot information for Windows 7 is still on the Vista drive. You'll need to move that before you format the drive.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where that might be?  I thought that by removing the Vista entry into the bootloader I got rid of what I needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the Vista installation in place before the Windows 7 installation?  The bootloader is probably on that hard drive, and that's why it won't let you format it - because it knows you booted to it!  You need to completely rebuild a bootloader on the W7 drive (you should be able to do this with EasyBCD).

Comment: Yes, the Vista installation was first and then I set up Windows 7. Using EasyBCD I removed the entry for Vista to boot to, is rebuilding the bootloader a separate operation?

Comment: You removed the entry, but the bootloader is still physically located on the Vista drive, so you can't format that drive.  You need a new bootloader on a different drive.